# Add Int of similar string in contents of Array[String,Int] in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a Array[String,Int], I want to add the int values of same Strings.

```
    val hashed_values=sentences.map(s => (getMd5(s),1))
```

I want to add the values of similar Strings. (getMD5 returns string)

Comment: What is an `array[String,Int]`? do you mean an `Array[(String,Int)]`? is the `sentences` reference supposed to be of that type? Also, you probably shouldn't reuse the same reference name inside of the call to `map`.

Comment: I updated the code likewise, I have sentences as Array[String]. I want to count the occurrence of same sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like:

```
 val sentences = Array("Hello World", "World", "Hello World")

  sentences.map{
    sentence => (getMd5(sentence), sentence)
    }
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .mapValues {
      values =>
        values.head._2 -> values.length
    }.values.toMap
```

Comment: This is what I have done already, but this does not let me search me by key.

Comment: is the count correct? or you have a different issue which you did explain in your post? what search do you want?

Comment: the count is correct, but i need a way to search("Hello World") and get the count in return.

Comment: why do you need md5? you can just groupBy sentence

Comment: Thats the requirement of my function overall. I need to search by hashvalue.

Comment: Thanks, I needed some changes which I made. Thanks again